# Find occurences in the last 6 months row by row using Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have a dataset like this:

```
  id_police id_sinistre    datesurv
0      p123        s120  01/01/2018
1      p123        s121  03/01/2018
2      p123        s122  05/05/2018
3      p222        s123  04/05/2018
4      p222        s124  02/12/2018
5      p433        s125  07/08/2018
6      p433        s126  08/09/2018
7      p433        s127  10/10/2018
```

My goal is to find last occurences of `id_police` in last 6 months for each row like this:

```
  id_police id_sinistre    datesurv  occ
0      p123        s120  01/01/2018    0
1      p123        s121  03/01/2018    1
2      p123        s122  05/05/2018    2
3      p222        s123  04/05/2018    0
4      p222        s124  02/12/2018    0
5      p433        s125  07/08/2018    0
6      p433        s126  08/09/2018    1
7      p433        s127  10/10/2018    2
```

I think I will need `.duplicated` or `.groupby` but I am not sure how to use them... Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If 6 months should be simplify for 6 * 30 days use custom lambda function with `diff`, compare by value and last cumulative sum:

```
df['datesurv'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datesurv'], dayfirst=True)

df = df.sort_values(['id_police','datesurv'])

f = lambda x: (x.diff().dt.days < 30 * 6).cumsum()
df['occ'] = df.groupby('id_police')['datesurv'].apply(f)

print (df)
  id_police id_sinistre   datesurv  occ
0      p123        s120 2018-01-01    0
1      p123        s121 2018-01-03    1
2      p123        s122 2018-05-05    2
3      p222        s123 2018-05-04    0
4      p222        s124 2018-12-02    0
5      p433        s125 2018-08-07    0
6      p433        s126 2018-09-08    1
7      p433        s127 2018-10-10    2
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option would be to [`GroupBy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) the `datesurv` and also using [`pd.Grouper`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html) to create groups of 6 months and take the [`cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
df.datesurv = pd.to_datetime(df.datesurv, format='%d/%m/%Y')
g = pd.Grouper(key='datesurv', freq='6MS')
df.assign(occ=df.groupby(['id_police', g]).cumcount())

   id_police id_sinistre   datesurv  occ
0      p123        s120 2018-01-01    0
1      p123        s121 2018-01-03    1
2      p123        s122 2018-05-05    2
3      p222        s123 2018-05-04    0
4      p222        s124 2018-12-02    0
5      p433        s125 2018-08-07    0
6      p433        s126 2018-09-08    1
7      p433        s127 2018-10-10    2
```